# HTML form with post method sent get request

Tags: html

I had a form which used post method. However, after I clicked sumbmit, only get request was sent. Can I please know why?

```
<form action="/review_page/{{yelp_id}}" method=post>
    <label for="review-score">Your overall rating of this restaurant</label>
    <select name="score" id="review-score">
        {% for num in range(1,6) %}
          <option value="{{ num }}">{{ num }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <div>
        <label for="review-title">Title of your review</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="review-title">
    </div>
   
    <div>
        <label for="reviewText">Your review</label>
        <div>
            <textarea name="review" id="reviewText" data-minlen="100" data-maxlen="20000" 
            placeholder="Tell people about your experience"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Your Review">

</form>
```

Please also find my routes below.

@app.route("/review_page/<yelp_id>", methods=["POST"])
def save_user_review(yelp_id):
"""Save user review into database"""

```
user_id = session.get("user_id")

print(user_id)


if user_id is None:
    flash("Please log in to leave a review")
    return redirect(f"/review_page/{yelp_id}")
else:
    user = User.query.get(session["user_id"])
    title = request.form.get("title")
    score = int(request.form.get("score"))
    review = request.form.get("review")
    yelp_id = yelp_id

    rating = crud.create_rating_without_pic(user, title, score, review, yelp_id)
    db.session.add(rating)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(f"/rest_details/{yelp_id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is it.

You have this

`<form action="/review_page/{{yelp_id}}" method=post>`

And probably you should have this

`<form action="/review_page/{{yelp_id}}" method="post">`

Comment: It was method="post" and it was not working as well

Comment: Are you using Django?

Comment: No, I use Flask and Jinja

Comment: In your route your specify the method?

Comment: Yes, let me post my route as well

Comment: Hm... I don't know what could be the issue

Comment: I spent a couple of hours on it and still cant fix it....Thanks for coming and help anyway~

Comment: I remembered something, in your route, you can try to change the methods, from ["POST"]  to ["GET", "POST"], I was thinking and I had a similar problem

Comment: Thanks. I tried but still not working. The weird thing is that almost all the forms with post methods are not working now... I really wanna know why.